# Oledb Exception In IIS But Works In IIS-express (Exception: E_FAIL(0x80004005))

Tags: c#, asp.net, excel, ms-access, iis

I have an Web Application which takes xls Files As Input And Store them To database And then updates UI. 
Here configuration details of my computer:

1. Microsoft Access Database Engine 2007 (To Read Data From Excel Files),Here 
   Connection String I am Using Is:
   Connection String="Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source={0};Extended 
   Properties='Excel 12.0;'"

   2. Database Client:Oracle11g
   3. OS: Windows10(64bit)
   4. Visual Studio2015

   where here i am replacing This {0} with file path

   there are totally 5 Excel Files(.xls format) here the sizes of  5 Excel Files

   1ExcelFile(Size: 339KB)

   2ExcelFile(Size: 2160KB)

   3ExcelFile(Size: 12KB)

   4ExcelFile(Size: 12KB)

   5ExcelFile(Size: 319KB)

**Problem:**

When I deployed this web app to my local IIS then I am getting the exception

**Exception: System.Data.OleDb.OleDbException (0x80004005): No error message 
 available, result code: E_FAIL(0x80004005)**

actually if this Exception comes on reading The 1ExcelFile then it's OK , But it 
 has read 1ExcelFile and saved the 1ExcelFile to oracle DB,
 After whenever my web app is trying to access The file 2ExcelFile then this 
 Exception rises.Reason I think the size Of 2ExcelFile( which is big when 
 compared to other files)

**But Everything works fine and all the ExcelFiles has been read and saved to 
  Oracle DB when I run from VS2015(iisexpress)** .

I have read about this Exception what I have understood it will come whenever we try to read the file which is not there, but I have the file in that location.

**I think issue is of IIS Configuration with oledb**

unable to get the exact point why it is happening ?

Any Suggestions Are Helpful.

Comment: The Bizarre Capitalisation Makes This Very Hard To Read.

Comment: Sorry Alex K I Have Edited My Question Just Now

Comment: But Still Every Other Word Starts With A Capital.

Comment: @PeterBons now i have edited please read it now